# In Silverstripe, how can I automate the CMS field creation for Pages like it works in DataObjects?

Tags: silverstripe, scaffolding, silverstripe-4

In `DataObjects`, the `getCMSFields` method creates all the appropriate CMS Fields automatically (it is called scaffolding). However, in classes that extend `SiteTree` (i.e. Pages) this does not happen.

How can I use this form field scaffolding in Pages?

Answer (score 2):

Besides calling DataObject::getCMSFields() as you already suggested in your own answer, it is also possible to instantiate a scafolder directly:

```php
public function getCMSFields() {
        // with tabs
        $scaffolder = new FormScaffolder($this);
        $scaffolder->restrictFields = ['Title', 'Content'];
        $scaffolder->tabbed = true;
        $fields = $scaffolder->getFieldList();
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', [
            new MySpecialFieldWithCustomOptions('Links', 'My Links', $foobar),
        ]);
        return $fields;
}
```

```php
public function getCMSFields() {
        // without tabs
        $scaffolder = new FormScaffolder($this);
        $scaffolder->restrictFields = ['Title', 'Content'];
        $fields = $scaffolder->getFieldList();
        $fields->push(
            new MySpecialFieldWithCustomOptions('Links', 'My Links', $foobar)
        );
        return $fields;
}
```

This will work with any DataObject ($this has to be an instace of DataObject). Pages a subclass of DataObjects.
`restrictFields` is optional, if not provided, it will do all fields it can find.

Answer (score 0):

We go back to `DataObject` and get the scaffolded fields:

```php
use SilverStripe\ORM\DataObject;
use Page;

class MyPage extends Page 
{
    private static $db = [
        'MyField' => 'Varchar',
    ];

    private static $has_one = [
        'MyRelation' => 'MyClass',
    ];

    public function getCMSFields()
    {
        // fields from Page class
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();
        // fields from DataObject class.
        $fieldRepository = DataObject::getCMSFields();

        $fields->addFieldsToTab(
            'Root.MyExtraFields',
            [
                $fieldRepository->dataFieldByName('MyField'),
                $fieldRepository->dataFieldByName('MyRelationID'),
            ]
        );

        return $fields;

    }
}
```